# Lookup consts in a class at runtime

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Is it theoretically possible to lookup the `consts` in a `class` at runtime?

I have a static class full of consts similar to this:

```
public static class Constants {
    public const string Yes = "Yes";
    public const string No = "No";
}
```

and I was wondering if I could create a UnitTest that could take the Constants class, and read all of the consts from within it. The idea being, I could write one unit test, that is then run against all of the const strings. So if I add more string to the class, the unit test does not have to change.

I believe the answer here is no... but thought it was worth asking just in case!

Comment: Look into Reflection (specific example for constants: http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2003/02/20/2708.aspx)

Comment: What type of unit test would you write against constants?

Comment: The class above is trivial, but in the actual code, the constants refer to RegEx strings, which we want to test are valid at compile time.

Comment: If your class contained regexes instead of just regex strings, wouldn't they all automatically be tested for validity at compile time?

Comment: Yes they would, but we would have a few thousand RegEx instances hanging around in memory, rather than a few thousand strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var t= typeof(Constants).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                    .Where(f => f.IsLiteral);
foreach (var fieldInfo in t)
{
   // name of the const
   var name = fieldInfo.Name;

   // value of the const
   var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
}
```

Comment: Replaced the . with a ; at the end of the first line, but other than that used this code verbatim. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using reflection you can use the `IsLiteral` property of the field to determine whether or not it is a constant:

```
var consts = myType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(fld => fld.IsLiteral);
```

You can then do as required with these in your unit test.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but as far as I recall `IsLiteral` gives true for `readonly` fields as well, so your need to test for `!fld.IsInitOnly` to filter them out.